# Изменение навигационного контейнера в responsiveslides.js

Tags: html, jquery

Я хочу добавить слайдер http://responsiveslides.com/ к сайту. В данном слайдере есть возможность поменять навигацию, которая по умолчанию состоит из маркированного списка, при помощи тега  navContainer: "" , что я собственно и хочу сделать. Но контейнер, который я привязываю, игнорируется и переключение всё так же происходит при помощи маркированного списка. Что я делаю не так?

```js
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../responsiveslides.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo.css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
  
  <script>
    $(function () {
      // Slideshow 2
      $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
        auto: false,
        pager: true,
        speed: 300,
        maxwidth: 540,
        navContainer: ".slider-buttons"
      });
  });
  </script>
  
</head>
<body>
<!-- Slideshow 2 -->
    <ul class="rslides"">
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/2.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/3.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="slider-buttons">
      <div class="slider-button1"><a href="#" class="slider-button1">Кнопка 1</a></div>
      <div class="slider-button2"><a href="#" class="slider-button2">Кнопка 2</a></div>
      <div class="slider-button3"><a href="#" class="slider-button3">Кнопка 3</a></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы взглянете на список параметров:

> `"navContainer": "", // Selector: Where auto generated controls should 
>                         be appended to, default is after the <ul>`

Как видим, `navContainer` - это контейнер, ***в который будет добавлена сгенерированная навигация***. Т.е. навигация *всегда* будет генериться скриптом, а единственное, что Вы можете выбрать - это контейнер *куда* она будет добавлена. Возможность добавить свою навигацию вместо дефолтной - отсутствует.

А вот это из JS:

```
if (options.navContainer) {
    $(settings.navContainer).append($pager);
} else {
    $this.after($pager);
}
```

Если `navContainer` задан, то навигация добавляется в него, а если нет, то по умолчанию.